# Best way to store lot of data - SQL

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I want to design a database which is going to consists of really lot of columns, since it's a web game's inventory but there is going to be really lot of things.

It would probably call for names like "item_1", "item_2" but is that even ideal?

When I plan it to be extended over 1 000 items?

I need to SELECT later if the user has them, every single one.

I plan to use MariaDB and Laravel framework with Jetstream, Livewire and Tailwind.css.

Comment: One row per item seems like a much better solution.

Comment: 1000 is not really a lot of data for a database :)

Comment: Entering a new item should **not** lead to a change in the table structure. So think about EAV.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question? Why not check out some basic tutorials abour normalization, to avoid having too much columns?

Comment: @NicoHaase i just wanted to ask if it isn't too much for a DB to work with when I need to display it later, I wanted to build the whole structure as like table - Inventory, user (user's id to pair with main users table), item_1 (int, count of items), item_2, ....

Comment: "Too much work for a DB" - for which part? 1000 items in normalized form? No, that will not put any work on a DB server. 1000 columns in a table, with the chance of way more? That will cause trouble on all sides, both in the DB and in your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do anything, read about

- [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
- [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF)
- [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_2NF)
- [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_3NF)
- [BCNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)

Bearing in mind the knowledge you thusly accumulate, you should reach to a conclusion similar to having some tables like these:

- item_types(id, name, ...)
- user(username, password, ...)
- inventory(user_id, item_type_id, amount)